# Objective-C - Better search than NSCaseInsensitiveSearch? Keywords? NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, plist, nspredicate

currently i am using this to search through my array of dictionaries (from plist file):

```
for(NSDictionary *wine in mainArray)
    {
        NSString *wineName = [wine objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSRange range = [wineName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
            [searchArray addObject:wine];
    }
```

In this question I am going to have this plist as an example:

```
<array>
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Banana One (Yellow)</string>
  <key>value</key>
  <string>1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Apple Two (White)</string>
  <key>value</key>
  <string>2</string>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Pineapple Three (Orange)</string>
  <key>value</key>
  <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
</array>
```

(Do not care about the value)

Ok, When I'm using the UISearchBar with NSCaseInsensitiveSearch i can simply search through the array `(ObjectForKey=@"name")` without think about Case. Good!

for example i can search for:`@"banana"` and find the :Banana One (Yellow)

and i can search for:`@"two"` and find the :Apple Two (White)

and i can search for:`@"banana` one" and find the :Banana One (Yellow)

I can also search for:`@"Orange"` and find the :Pineapple Three (Orange)

But only if the search is in right sequence

I can't search for:`@"One Banana"` or `@"Yellow One"` or `@"Yellow Banana"`
I would really like to be able to search like this, maybe using keywords?

maybe something like this?:

```
for(NSDictionary *wine in mainArray)
{
NSArray *myArray = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *wineName = [wine objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSRange range = [wineName rangeOfString:myArray options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        [searchArray addObject:wine];
}
```

I know that this really won't work but I think you know what I mean?
So, How to be able to search for example:`@"one banana"` and find :Banana One (Yellow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out following solution using [`NSPredicate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003714).

```
    NSArray *objects = @[@"Banana One",@"Apple Two"];
    NSString *searchString = @"one banana";
    NSArray *searchComoponents = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSMutableString *format = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] \"%@\"",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchComoponents[0]]];
    for (int i = 1; i < searchComoponents.count; i++) {
        [format appendFormat:@" AND SELF CONTAINS[c] \"%@\"",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchComoponents[i]]];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format]];
    NSArray *filtered = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

For a short explanation: `SELF` is the current object in the array, which should be proofed, `CONTAINS` looks, whether the left object contains the right object, and `[c]` makes it all caseinsensitive.
So for every keyword in the searchString, you add the condition to the predicateformat, so that at the end, you should have a NSPredicate with this format: 
SELF CONTAINS[c] *object1* AND SELF CONTAINS[c] *object2* ....
The last line creates a filtered array using this NSPredicate. For more information on the predicateFormat look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795).

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Thanks DevFan for your answer!
I needed to edit some things for example SELF to SELF.name to specify the key in my array of dictionaries.

```
NSArray *searchComoponentsWithEmptyStrings = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSMutableArray *searchComoponents = [searchComoponentsWithEmptyStrings mutableCopy];
        [searchComoponents removeObject:@""]; //remove empty strings from the array (only works with NSMutableArray)

        NSMutableString *format = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"SELF.name CONTAINS[c] '%@'",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchComoponents[0]]];
        for (int i = 1; i < searchComoponents.count; i++) {
            [format appendFormat:@"AND SELF.name CONTAINS[c] '%@'",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchComoponents[i]]];
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format]];
        searchArray = [mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and now I can also search for @"banana " (with space at the end) and still find Banana One (Yellow)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should split the NSString "Banana One (Yellow)" in an array ("Banana", "One", "(Yellow)") and  check if one of those contains to your searchtext.

```
    NSString *searchText = @"One";
    NSString *txt = @"Banana One (Yellow)";
    NSArray* splitString = [txt componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for(int i = 0; i < [splitString count]; i++){
        if([[splitString objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound) {
            return txt;
        }
    }
```